# Does security scanning a camera with battery inside cause damage to the sensor?

Tags: lens, sensor, security

I was at 911 memorial last week. My Fuji S-1 Pro camera was scanned with the battery installed. Security personnel would not let me remove battery. Since then, a dark spot shows up on photos. This has happened before and the CCD assembly had to be replaced at a cost of $400. Is scanning to really blame for this?

Comment: Is this dark spot appears on just the same location everytime? Please elaborate your question of what exactly your concern is.

Comment: Also post some images if you can.

Comment: If you could post a link to a sample picture with the problem it would help. Once you get enough reputation you can post the image directly here.

Comment: You could post a link to a photo or photos. Or email to me and I'll add it if you wish. See profile for email address. Sensor dirt a possibility. More information needed before best advice on possible effect of scan can be given, but it seems unlikely that the scan caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Having the battery in the camera shouldn't make a bit of difference if the camera was turned off.  I'm also not aware of any particular reason that the scanning equipment should have caused a problem, but what you are describing sounds like a dead or hot pixel.  This is just something that can happen on cameras unfortunately.  It's also possibly some dust on the sensor or lens.

Comment: I don't know which scanners are there at 911 Memorial, but I can tell from my experience that usual airports scanners never damaged my cameras, even with batteries installed, even after several passes in a short time.
Usually they were switched off in my bag, so I can't tell if they could be damaged if they were on, but I guess not.

Comment: Probably a lost cause, but whoever downvoted could you please comment as to why.

Comment: @Gerlos - yes, even if it was turned on, it shouldn't make a difference either, but when the camera is off, there shouldn't be any power to the sensor, so it's the same state with or without battery when off.